# React Browser Router v6 not rendering element on refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Routing seems to be working fine until I go to a child route and refresh the page. After refreshing the page the element disappears and the only way to fix it is to go to the base route and refresh the page. I have the entire app wrapped around BrowserRouter in the index.js file.

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";

const mount = (element) => {
  createRoot(
    element,
  ).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App/>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  const devRoot = document.querySelector('#_marketing-dev-root');

  if (devRoot)
    mount(devRoot);
}

export {mount};
```

App.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import {Routes, Route, BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import {createTheme, ThemeProvider, StyledEngineProvider} from '@mui/material/styles';

import Landing from './components/Landing';
import Pricing from './components/Pricing';

const mdTheme = createTheme();

export default () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
        <ThemeProvider
          theme={mdTheme}
        >
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Landing/>}/>
            <Route path="pricing" element={<div>Hello</div>}/>
          </Routes>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </StyledEngineProvider>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In the Landing component I have some links that looks like:

```
                <Grid item>
                  <Link to="pricing">
                    <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
                      Pricing
                    </Button>
                  </Link>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                  <Link to="pricing">
                    <Button variant="outlined" color="primary">
                      Pricing
                    </Button>
                  </Link>
                </Grid>
```

Clicking on these links route me to the correct element. But, once I get to that element and refresh the page it just disappears. No errors or warnings in the console.

Comment: Do the routes work when running the app locally? Is it only a problem when the app is deployed out on a server? See if https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/ helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no the routes do not work locally. I'm able to start the app and navigate within the app to other routes, but as soon as I refresh the page the element disappears unless I'm on the base route "/".

Comment: I see, well, this may make making a reproducible example easier then. How are you running the app locally? Could you try creating a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the suggestions everyone. I found out it was a webpack preference that was causing this issue.

Old Webpack preference

```
  devServer: {
    port: 8081,
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: 'index.html',
    },
  },
```

New Webpack preference

```
  devServer: {
    port: 8081,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
```